Change Flutter splash on web (a screen before the default white splash)
I have seen some questions asking similar but they all keep referring to splash screen as white which isn't the case for me. I see a native default screen and then a white splash screen. (See the attached image).
I'm building PWA so I am hoping to get a solution for web. Files in Android or iOs folders don't really help.


Provide some code of main function

Have you tried splash_screen packages?

@Firaun the package actually overrides something, right? What and where's that? Wanted to test that.

The above package does nothing more then adding a div in the index.html and remove this div just before running appRunner(). Check out how to create better and more custom splash on flutter official website
